# "external_login_url" customize Plone-login-form

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I need to customize Plone login form without make changes in plone original login-form https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_login/login_form.cpt so there are two ways first i use override.zcml to change login-form :

```
   <browser:page
    for="OFS.interfaces.IApplication"
    name="plone-root-login"
    class="Products.CMFPlone.browser.admin.RootLoginRedirect"
    permission="cmf.ManagePortal"
    template="templates/login.pt"
    />
```

and another a simple login.pt file.It generating  an Trace:

```
 File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.3-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/browser/admin.zcml", line 43.2-48.8
    <browser:page
        for="OFS.interfaces.IApplication"
        name="plone-root-login"
        class=".admin.RootLoginRedirect"
        permission="cmf.ManagePortal"
        />
File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/my_app.egg/my/app/browser/overrides.zcml", line 7.4-12.10
      <browser:page
          for="OFS.interfaces.IApplication"
          name="plone-root-login"
          class=".admin.RootLoginRedirect"
          permission="cmf.ManagePortal"
          />
```

And **Second Method:** external_login_url in default/propertiesTool.xml i tried but changes not reflected

Comment: @keul Please have a look may you can suggest me better

Comment: overrides.zcml should go in the root of your egg product.  Also is the egg properly named? The directory my_app looks suspicious to me.

Comment: its just dummy data app egg is structured proper...ok is there any another way to customize Plone login form

Comment: Did you put overrides.zcml in the root of your egg product ? (i.e. under /my/app/ NOT /my/app/browser)

Comment: please update the error message then, you also shouldn't reference overrides.zcml from configure.zcml.  And try to give more details https://plone.org/documentation/kb/help